# The remainders of the terms of a recursive sequence

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $a_n$ be the sequence defined by $a_1 = 3, \ a_{n+1} = 3^{a_n}$. Let $b_n$ be the remainder when $a_n$ is divided by $100$. What is $b_{2004}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that by [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), $3^{20}\equiv 1 \pmod{100}$.
Therefore $a_2=3^1=3$, $a_3=3^3=27$, and
$$a_4=3^{a_3}=3^{27}=3^{20}\cdot 3^7\equiv 3^7=2187\equiv 87 \pmod{100}.$$
Now $a_4=100q+87$ for some $q\in\mathbb{Z}$ and
$$a_5=3^{a_4}=3^{100q+87}\equiv (3^{20})^{50q}\cdot (3^{20})^4\cdot 3^7\equiv 3^7\equiv 87 \pmod{100}.$$
Can you take it from here?